# All references in list point to 'this'

Tags: c#, .net, mono, unity-game-engine

Running c# .NET 3.5 code in Unity is producing a really weird issue

```
class X
{
    static List<X> _l = new List<X>();

    public X()
    {
        _l.Add(this);
        Debug.Log(_l.Count(x=>x==this));
    }
}
```

For each object that I create, the counter increases by 1... what gives? This is of course a snippet from a bigger application but the core issue is simple; when adding to a List from the constructor and then retrieving itself from said list should give 1 result and 1 result only, no matter how the object is created; right?

If more code is required I'll add it but I'm hoping someone has experienced this before. I'm not sure what version of Mono Unity uses but I think it's 2.0.

Comment: @I4V: That's not what he's trying to do.

Comment: @l4V But then each class gets it own list so of course it will only ever have 1 element.. not the point is it?

Comment: The `X` class doesn't happen to override `Object.Equals` or implement equality `==` overrides, does it?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It does inherit UnityEngine.Object so you may be on to something there. Edit: Yeap UnityEngine.Object has said operators... that explains a lot!

Comment: @natli try changing the check to: `_l.Count(x => Object.ReferenceEquals(x, this)` and see if it works properly.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'm sure it would have but I just removed the inheritance (static methods anyway) could you add it as an answer so I can close this?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: @LexLi Sorry, had no idea.. I bet you get that often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity may be auto-implementing the `Object.Equals` method and equality operator overrides which may be causing the `==` check to not be checking *reference* equality but some other criteria.

Removing the inheritance to `MonoBehaviour` (or `UnityEngine.Object`), implementing your own operator overrides, or changing the expression to `_l.Count(x => Object.ReferenceEquals(x, this)` may resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your code, and it works fine for me (it prints `1` everytime a new object is created).

I guess, like Chris Sinclair said in the comments, you are overriding the `operator ==` or inheriting from a class doing so.

You could redefine your operator:

```
public static bool operator ==(X @this, X other)
{
    return object.Equals(@this, other);
}
```